# where is storedVars in soda

Tags: node.js, selenium-rc

How to get [storedVars](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/0.8.0/reference.html#storedVars) array in  [selenium soda](https://github.com/LearnBoost/soda) test?
I expect that `storeEval` puts variable with given name to array `storedVars`. But `storedVars` is undefined. Or maybe I don't know in what scope I can access it.

```
var soda = require('soda')
    , assert = require('assert');
var browser = soda.createClient({
    host: 'localhost'
    , port: 4444
    , url: 'http://jquery.com'
    , browser: 'firefox'
});
browser.session(function(err){
    browser.open('/', function(err, body, res){
            browser.storeEval(" window.jQuery('.logo').height();", "height", function(err, body, res){
                // ---------------------------------------------------------------
                // how to get storedVars['height'] here?
                // ReferenceError: storedVars is not defined
                // ---------------------------------------------------------------
                console.log ("height: "+storedVars['height'] ); 
                if (err)
                {
                    throw err;
                }
                browser.testComplete(function(){

                });

            });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your example above, you can access storedVars like this:

```
var soda = require('soda')
    , assert = require('assert');
var browser = soda.createClient({
    host: 'localhost'
    , port: 4444
    , url: 'http://jquery.com'
    , browser: 'firefox'
});
browser.session(function(err){
    browser.open('/', function(err, body, res){
        browser.storeEval("window.jQuery('.logo').height();", "height", function(err, body, res){
            browser.getEval('${height}',function(err,val){
                if(err !== null) throw err
                console.log(val)
                browser.testComplete(function(){ });
            });
        });
    });
})
```

One thing is to make sure not to call testComplete before you get them though!